# save image to specific album in photolibrary ios

Tags: ios, image

I am creating app to download images from net and save it to Custom Album in PhotoLibrary.

i have successfully save images to Custom Album. But, The Problem is That images saved in Custom Album are also stored in SavedPhotos Folder!

i just want to store that image in my custom album!
my code is

```
    ALAssetsLibrary* libraryFolder = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];


[libraryFolder saveImage:img toAlbum:@"libraryFolder" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error)

        {
            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
        }
];
```

Comment: show fully code for this ..

Comment: My code is working perfectly but the problem is that i got images in my custom album as well as in saved photos album also!

Comment: I think u also placed code for save in SavedPhotos Folder. without see ur code, I can't help :(